# Interact with React chart with Python Selenium

Tags: python, reactjs, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to press a button in a React chart on the webpage https://coinmarketcap.com/currencies/vitex-coin/ by using Python Selenium. I tried with xpath but I'd like a more general way as it should work with other webpages from the same website. Also, I'd like to press the download button and select the csv. In particular, I want to press the 'ALL' button first and then download the csv. Here's my attempt:

```
from selenium import webdriver

url='https://coinmarketcap.com/currencies/vitex-coin/'

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get(url)

button=driver.find_element('xpath', '/html/body/div[1]/div/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[3]/div/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/ul/li[5]')
button.click()
```

Thank you!
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not use Selenium when there is an [official API available](https://coinmarketcap.com/api/pricing/).

Using it you don't even need Python:

```bash
$ curl -s "https://api.coinmarketcap.com/data-api/v3.1/cryptocurrency/historical?id=5246&timeStart=1710950400&interval=1h&convertId=2781" | jq -r '.data.quotes | .[].quote | join(";")' | head
2781;0.0301149728;0.0306785583;0.0299433788;0.0304453918;3211.9;0;2024-03-20T17:59:59.999Z
2781;0.0304453918;0.0312453875;0.0304453918;0.0312453875;3293.57;0;2024-03-20T18:59:59.999Z
2781;0.0312453875;0.0312453875;0.030988754;0.0311885108;3292.49;0;2024-03-20T19:59:59.999Z
2781;0.0311885108;0.0320020032;0.0311216077;0.0319061864;3341.76;0;2024-03-20T20:59:59.999Z
2781;0.0319061864;0.0329405937;0.0317733378;0.0328081693;3478.13;0;2024-03-20T21:59:59.999Z
2781;0.0328081693;0.032983508;0.0327805155;0.0328964901;3486.78;0;2024-03-20T22:59:59.999Z
2781;0.0328964901;0.0330497471;0.032854913;0.0329165432;3485.85;0;2024-03-20T23:59:59.999Z
2781;0.0329165432;0.0331003516;0.0328021016;0.0329552787;3486.88;0;2024-03-21T00:59:59.999Z
2781;0.0329552787;0.0330204372;0.032891874;0.0329630517;3506.41;0;2024-03-21T01:59:59.999Z
2781;0.0329630517;0.0331759958;0.0329630517;0.0330223475;3507.45;0;2024-03-21T02:59:59.999Z
```

You can translate this to any language you like. Just get a free API key from their website and save yourself hours of debugging clunky Selenium code :D

Answer (score 1):

You can use below code, should work
FYI I have added code to maximise windows as Download csv button doesnt show properly if window is not maximised

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import time
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains

url = 'https://coinmarketcap.com/currencies/vitex-coin/'

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get(url)
driver.maximize_window()
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
allButton = wait.until(
    EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '(//ul[@class="react-tabs__tab-list"])[1]//li[text()="ALL"]')))
allButton.click()
exportButton = allButton.find_element(By.XPATH, "(//li//div[contains(@class,'custom-button-inner')])[2]")
actions = ActionChains(driver)
actions.move_to_element(exportButton).pause(1).click().perform()
downloadAsCsvButton = wait.until(
    EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//button[text()="Download price history (.csv)"]')))
downloadAsCsvButton.click()
# Wait for download to complete
time.sleep(10)
```

Comment: it seems the website changed a bit. The `"Download price history (.csv)"` seems not to work most of the time. I added a `div` as well but nothing. The webpage changes randomly but the reference should be stable. Please see the updated code below, now you have to deal with cookies pop up. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

the website changed a bit, here's my new attempt. The `"Download price history (.csv)"` seems not to work most of the time. I added a `div` as well but nothing. The webpage changes randomly but the reference should be stable. Please see the updated code below, now you have to deal with cookies pop up.

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import time
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains

url = 'https://coinmarketcap.com/currencies/render/'

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get(url)
driver.maximize_window()
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)

cookie_list=['//*[@id="onetrust-reject-all-handler"]', '//*[@id="onetrust-accept-btn-handler"]',
                 '/html/body/div[5]/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/div[2]/div/button[2]',
                 '/html/body/div[5]/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/div[2]/div/button[1]']
# interact with chart and press download button
for scroll in [0, 300, 600, 900, 1200]:
    try:
        driver.execute_script(f"window.scrollTo(0, {scroll});")
        allButton=WebDriverWait(driver, 3).until(
            EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '(//ul[@class="react-tabs__tab-list"])[1]//li[text()="All"] | (//ul[@class="react-tabs__tab-list"])[1]//li[text()="ALL"]')))

        allButton.click()
        break
    except:
        pass
    if check_cookies:
        for pp in cookie_list:
            try:              # close cookies
                cookie=WebDriverWait(driver, 2).until(
                    EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, pp)))
                cookie.click()
                break
            except:
                pass
exportButton=allButton.find_element(By.XPATH, "(//li//div[contains(@class,'custom-button-inner')])[2]")
actions=ActionChains(driver)
actions.move_to_element(exportButton).pause(2).click().perform()
downloadAsCsvButton=wait.until(
                    EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//button//div[text()="Download price history (.csv)"]')))
downloadAsCsvButton.click()
```